# How do I capture this latitude value in regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm calling a service that gives me back a latitude and longitude like this: `"Lat:42.747058 Long:-84.551892"`.

How do I capture the latitude value using regular expressions?
This code does not work.

```
string GPSLocation = "Lat:42.747058 Long:-84.551892";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(GPSLocation, "Lat:() ");
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    string latValue = matches[0].Value;
    return Decimal.Parse(latValue);
}
return 0M;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use regex for something simple like this

How about

```
string GPSLocation = "Lat:42.747058 Long:-84.551892";
var values = GPSLocation.split(" ");
if (values.Count > 0)
{
    string lat = values[0].split(":")[1];
    return Decimal.Parse(lat);
}
return 0M;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=Lat:)(-?\d+\.\d+)
```

In C#:

```
Regex.Matches(GPSLocation, "(?<=Lat:)(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)")[0].Value;
```

It simply matches a decimal number with an optional `-`-sign.

Comment: And use 1st group capture for value :)

Comment: No need to worry about the capture groups -- the look-behind will match a number that's preceded by "Lat:", but the "Lat:" won't be included in the match.  So whatever matches will be the number.  You could actually remove the second set of parens entirely and it'd still work.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you don't mind me putting a non-regex solution

```
    string GPSLocation = "Lat:42.747058 Long:-84.551892";
    string lat = GPSLocation.Substring(4, GPSLocation.IndexOf("Long") - 5);
    string lon = GPSLocation.Substring(GPSLocation.IndexOf("Long") + 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

`"Lat:()"` will match "Lat:", then capture an empty string.  Inside the parentheses you need to add the characters you want to capture, like this: `"Lat:([-.0-9]*)"`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`Lat:([\d.-]+) Long:([\d.-]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string GPSLocation = "Lat:42.747058 Long:-84.551892";
string latRegex = "Lat:-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]?0)\\.{1}\\d{1,6}"
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(GPSLocation, latRegex);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    ...
```

Regex shamelessly stolen from [RegexLib.com](http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=latitude)

Make sure to double up on your backslashes

Comment: Breaks if lat <= -91 or >= 91, or ( > -1 and < 1 ).

Comment: latitude is in the -90 to +90 range, outside of that range it's an incorrect value.

Comment: Ahh..yeah...i was thinking of longitude.  :P  But it still breaks for (-1..1).  A `?` before the 0 might fix that.

Answer (score 0):

with this String:`string GPSLocation = "Lat:42.747058 Long:-84.551892";`You can first use Split(':') then Use Split(' '): `string s=GPSLocation.Split(':')[1].Split(' ')[0]` then `s` Lat.

Answer (score 0):

With use of a regex object which you could compile and use again and again.

```
Decimal res;
string GPSLocation = "Lat:42.747058 Long:-84.551892";
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?<=Lat:)-?(\b[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\b)");
if (Decimal.TryParse(regexObj.Match(GPSLocation).Groups[1].Value, out res)){
     return res;
}
return 0M;
```